# Communicate two separated APIs

Tags: java, spring, service

I want to communicate among two separated APIs (Java API).
I have a rest API that receives data from a mobile App and I want to send these data to another API.
How can I do it?

Comment: If the other API is also a REST API you can just send data using HTTP clients (like Spring's [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)) preferably using POST calls to the other endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches. Those are the ones that come to my mind:

- For simple forwarding or simple transformation, we can use a framework like [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul).
- If we are on a microprofile-base project, we can use [Microprofile Rest Client](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client).
- If the downstream REST API provides an OpenAPI specification, we can use tools like [Swagger Codegen](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/) to generate the client code ([tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen)).
- We can use specialized frameworks, e.g. [Spring RestTemplate (article on baeldung)](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) or [OpenFeign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign).
- For enterprise integration, we can use specialized solutions [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) or [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/)

Comment: thank you for your response , can you exlplain  the third point please :   If the downstream REST API provides an OpenAPI specification, we can use tools like Swagger Codegen to generate the client code.

Comment: @marwa added a link to a tutorial over at baeldung.